# How to move grub on a different drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have 4 harddrives and 2 of them are ssds for windows and ubuntu.

```
sda: windows10
sdb: Ubuntu
sdc and sdd: data
```

When I installed Ubuntu it wrote grub on the windows drive. Now I'd like to install the bootloader on sdb and remove grub from the windows drive so that every drive can be booted on its own. I'll select the drive in bios. I found several similar questions, but that didn't work for me.

I tried to install grub via `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` but I couldn't find any other bootloader than my old one in bios. Here is what lsblk gives me:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdd                     8:48   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdd2                  8:50   0 931,2G  0 part 
└─sdd1                  8:49   0   200M  0 part 
sdb                     8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb2                  8:18   0   488M  0 part /boot
├─sdb3                  8:19   0 464,8G  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 448,8G  0 lvm  /
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   512M  0 part 
sdc                     8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdc2                  8:34   0 931,2G  0 part 
└─sdc1                  8:33   0   200M  0 part 
sda                     8:0    0 489,1G  0 disk 
├─sda4                  8:4    0 488,5G  0 part 
├─sda2                  8:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3                  8:3    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda1                  8:1    0   450M  0 part
```

Comment: Have you tried to boot from /dev/sdb?

Comment: Yes sure, but it tells me that it couldn't find anything and I had to reboot

Comment: Did `grub-install` finish successfully? What is the partition table type of `sdb`? If it’s GPT, you need a [grub_bios / ESP partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/667401/250300) there.